# Move an object using accelerometer

Tags: android, android-canvas

Hello :) I created a yellow canvas with a ball on it, now i'm trying to move the ball but I don't know how, it's the first time i'm using an accelerometer and it's my first time using canvas and draw.. So can you help me moving it?

Here is my code so far:

```
     package com.example.theball;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int c = Color.YELLOW;
private Canvas g;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    draw();
    }
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void draw ()
{
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getHeight();
    int height = display.getWidth();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);
    g = new Canvas(bitmap);
    g.drawColor(c);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawCircle(50, 10, 25, paint); 
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    layout.addView(imageView, params);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    setContentView(layout);   
}
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED: here is the new code, thanks to someone here from stackoverflow:

```
    package com.example.theball;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
     private SensorManager sensorManager;
        private Sensor accelerometer;
        private long lastUpdate;

        AnimatedView animatedView = null;
        ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
        public static int x;
        public static int y;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            accelerometer = sensorManager
                    .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

            animatedView = new AnimatedView(this);
            setContentView(animatedView);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

                x -= (int) event.values[0];
                y += (int) event.values[1];

            }
        }

        public class AnimatedView extends ImageView {

            static final int width = 50;
            static final int height = 50;

            public AnimatedView(Context context) {
                super(context);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

                mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
                mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xffffAC23);
                mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);

            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
                mDrawable.draw(canvas);
                invalidate();
            }
        }

    }
```